# how to locate a company on a map (mapkit iOS)

Tags: ios

I am developing a simple map where I want to locate a company on a map using, for example, the company name. e.g., "Apple Inc.".

Do you know how can I do this?

Thanks a lot!

REgards, Yashu

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "location of a company". I guess you mean the headquarter address. Once you have the address you can get the coordinates using mapkit geocoding API.

Comment: according to Apples "Location Awareness Programming Guide" you are able to use `CLGeoCoder` to get coordinates for 'Apple Inc.'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a class implementing the MKAnnotation protocol. Here is a example

```
@interface MapPin : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *subtitle;

- (id)initWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location placeName:(NSString *)placeName description:(NSString *)description;

@end
```

Here is the implementation:

```
@implementation MapPin

@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize title;
@synthesize subtitle;

- (id)initWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location placeName:placeName description:description {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        coordinate = location;
        title = placeName;
        [title retain];
        subtitle = description;
        [subtitle retain];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [title release];
    [subtitle release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Then, In your MapView you need add your company location as like below.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:35.936902 longitude:-79.024953] coordinate];//Here you need to mention your company latitude and longitude
MapPin *pin = [[MapPin alloc] initWithCoordinates:coord placeName:@"Apple Inc" description:@""];
[map addAnnotation:pin];
```

Hope this will help....

Comment: Hi Nandha, thanks for your reply. But how do I get "Here you need to mention your company latitude and longitude"? Is there a way to get it according to the company name? Thanks!

Comment: You can get your company latitude and longitude by using your company address. There are some websites which will do this for you, http://stevemorse.org/jcal/latlon.php. or you can get using IOS.

Comment: But if I only have the company name(not address)?

Comment: You can't get latitude and longitude without address.

Comment: Yes I can - this google has the API.

Comment: Can you tell me the API name?

Comment: you can use the info here:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/